# AJAX (jquery) + Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tooltip, title

I use an tooltip. When I hide the native browser function for the tooltip function, (remote Attr title), after an Ajax update there is no content at all! How can I fix this?

```
jQuery('.tooltip').each(function(){
   $(this).data('title',$(this).attr('title'));
   $(this).removeAttr('title');

   jQuery(this).hover(function()
   {
      tooltip.show($(this).data('title'));
   },
   function()
   {
      tooltip.hide();
   });
});
```

This is what I use when I load the page (also when I use the Ajax Request).

EDIT:
IT ONLY WON'T WORK INSIDE FANCYBOX POPUP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$(this).data('title',$(this).attr('title'));
$(this).removeAttr('title');
```

You're overwriting what's in the `title` key in data each time, including *after* you blanked out the attribute, instead do this:

```
if(!$.data(this, 'title')) {
  $.data(this, 'title', $(this).attr('title'));
}
$(this).removeAttr('title');
```

With this version we're checking if data is already populated, if it is then don't overwrite it with the now-empty `title` attribute.